# COCOA: Showing a window on top without giving it focus

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to emulate what growl does with an app that I have. At a certain point I want to display a window on top all other open windows, but I don't want to lose focus on the active app.

Right now the code that I have is:

```
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
[self makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

This code will put the window on top, but also makes the current app the key window, which is undesired in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the window level as appropriate:

```
[myWindow setLevel:NSFloatingWindowLevel];
```

For other possible window level constants check the [NSWindow class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-SW75).